# When a base type list contains a base class and interfaces, the base class must come first in the list

Tags: c#, oop

While going through Interfaces on MSDN, they mentioned a statement:

> When a base type list contains a base class and interfaces, the base class must come first in the list.

Can some one clear this statement with example as I am not able to understand it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not valid according to the specs (interface first, then base class):

```
public class X : ISomeInterface, BaseClass { }
```

While this is (base class first, then interface):

```
public class X : BaseClass, ISomeInterface { }
```